# "No tests found" while running the tests through gradle

Tags: selenium-webdriver, gradle, testing, cucumber, junit5

I'm getting the "No tests found for given includes:" error while trying to run the tests using gradle. I created new fresh project just to get a hang of Cucumber/Junit but I can't figure out why I cannot actually run it.
Here is my cucumber runner class:

```
package features.selenium.runner;

import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Cucumber;

@Cucumber
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/features",
        glue = "features.selenium.stepdefinition"
)
public class CucumberRunner {}
```

There is my first simple test:

```
package features.selenium.stepdefinition;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;

public class SimpleTest {

  @When("Test")
  public void passOn() {
    assertThat("test").isEqualTo("test");
    System.out.println("TEST");
  }

  @Then("First simple test with Cucumber")
  public void passMe() {
    assertThat("test").isEqualTo("test");
    System.out.println("TEST");
  }
}
```

and there is my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id "io.freefair.lombok" version "6.5.0.3"
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
java.targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    //Http client library
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.14'

    //Jackson utility library to parse POJO to JSON
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.14.2'

    //Selenium Framework Library
    implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '4.8.1'

    //Library for random string generation in TestEventDataInitializer.java
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0'

    // Testing frameworks and libraries
    implementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.8.1'
    testImplementation platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.1')

    implementation 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-suite-api:1.8.0-M1'

    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.8.1'
    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0"
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.10.0'
    testImplementation 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.23.1'

    // Cucumber
    testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-java:6.10.4'
    testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:6.10.4'
    testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-picocontainer:6.10.4'
    testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-junit-platform-engine:6.10.4'

    // Logging libraries
    testImplementation 'org.codehaus.janino:janino:3.1.9'
    implementation 'org.codehaus.janino:janino:3.1.9'

    testImplementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.4.5'
    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.4.5'

    testImplementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.4.5'
    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.4.5'

    // General purpose libraries
    implementation 'io.vavr:vavr:1.0.0-alpha-4'

    //CSV files handler
    implementation 'com.opencsv:opencsv:5.7.1'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.qameta.allure/allure-testng
    implementation group: 'io.qameta.allure', name: 'allure-testng', version: '2.23.0'

}
wrapper {
    gradleVersion = "7.6"
}


test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I tried changing the the run and build configuration to use IDE instead of gradle in intellij and tests worked fine, but for some reason can't figure out why it's not working while using gradle. Maybe there is something I'm missing in my dependencies? I already looked at some similar questions but none of the answers worked.

Comment: If anything your dependencies are a mess, you're mixing multiple versions of JUnit and I'm not sure those converge with Cucumber. Try the https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton instead